# Get nearest match through multiple line using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, protractor

I have following output from Protractor test and I'm trying to parse and find name of failed spec:

```
Specs: /var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace//tests/js/e2e/ui_e2e/tests/test_one.js
Selenium URL: http://10.20.40.54:4444/wd/hub

..... number of different strings here....

Executed 25 of 25 specs SUCCESS in 1 min 23 secs.
-----
Specs: /var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace//tests/js/e2e/ui_e2e/tests/test_two.js

..... number of different strings here....

UnknownError: Due to a previous error, this job has already finished. You can learn more at
```

I'm using following regex:

```
(?:Specs:)(?:[\s\S])*(?=UnknownError(.*?))
```

However, it matches too wide section from first string, swallowing string with `test_two.js`.

How can I avoid swallowing and narrow match to have it like:

```
Specs: /var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace//tests/js/e2e/ui_e2e/tests/test_two.js

..... number of different strings here....

UnknownError: Due to a previous error, this job has already finished. You can learn more at
```

Comment: I think you are not looking for a "nearest" match, but for the shortest "window" between the start and end delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not looking for a "nearest" match, but for the shortest "window" between the start and end delimiters.

You may use

```
/^Specs:(?:(?!^Specs:)[\s\S])*UnknownError:\s*(.*)/gm
```

Or its more efficient unrolled variant:

```
/^Specs:.*(?:\r?\n(?!Specs:).*)*UnknownError:\s*(.*)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/raz6g2/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `Specs:` - a sequence of literal chars
- `(?:(?!^Specs:)[\s\S])*` - a tempered greedy token matching any char that does not start a sequence of a line start, `Specs:` (in the unrolled variant, the same is done with `.*(?:\r?\n(?!Specs:).*)*` subpattern)
- `UnknownError:` - a substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 1 capturing any zero or more chars other than line break chars.